# the argument of the promise object's method then()'s callback function

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am new to angular, I did some research but still cannot find an answer...,
I have the following code:

```
promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
  return result + 1;
});
```

Why we can use `result` as the argument  of the callback function? How the returned stuff of `promiseA` becomes `result` ?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Because that's how promises are defined. Resolved value (single) becomes an argument of the next `then` handler. Perhaps you confuse "returned value" which is a promise object and "resolved value" of a promise?

Comment: so it's a definition of angular, and we just use it as that. the resolution of a promise will become the argument of the callback function inside `.then()`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with AngularJS. It's just a modified library used and it is called `$q`. The promises are defined independently https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises, https://www.promisejs.org/. And has various [implementations](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/blob/master/implementations.md). (from which IMHO bluebird is the undisputed winner)

Answer (score 1):

A promise is simply an object used to represent the pending activity, don't confuse it with the result of that activity.

The resolved value is passed to the success callback that was given to the `.then()` method. If promises are chained together then the value returned from that callback becomes the value passed to the next `.then()` (or if the value returned is also a promise the resolution of that promise is passed to the next `.then()`).

So in your particular example we don't know where `result` came from: whatever created `promiseA` simply ensured it resolved with that value. However we do know that `promiseB` will resolve with the value `result+1` because that's what you returned.

Answer (score 1):

When `promiseA` completes ("resolves"), it will call the function that you pass to the `then()` function, and pass the result into that function. So let's say I had a promise that is requesting information from a database query. Let's say it's going to (eventually) give me the phone number for a user. I'd set up my code to print that out like this:

```
myPromise.then(function(phoneNum) {
    console.log(phoneNum);
});
```

The reason we can't just say `var result = myPromise()` is because a promise executes in a different flow that the rest of the code. We need to set up a function to handle the result **when it's done**

Answer (score 0):

Check how using the $q service you can `defer` the promise returned and process in sucesives callbacks, the `defer.promise`it's the key.

```
var promiseB = myService.response().then(function(result){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            defer.resolve(result);
            return defer.promise;
        });
promiseB.then(function(result){
            console.log("In promise B ===>", result);
        });
```

check this codepen: http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/ONjMrR?editors=0010